# Calculating time-series as a percentage of total

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I'm looking at county-level procurement data (millions of bills) and plotting time-series with matplotlib and pandas using `groupby`:

```
dataframe_slice.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).bill_amount.sum().plot
```

where bill_amount is a column of floats that shows how much was billed. How can I change the graph to show the `dataframe_slice` as a percentage of total dataframe `bill_amount`?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an out-of-the-box pandas function for that (but I am hoping to be proven wrong). Imho, you have to calculate the percentage per group by calculating the `total_sum`, then determining the percentage per group aggregation. Stand-alone code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#fake data generation
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
n = 200
start = pd.to_datetime("2017-07-17")
end   = pd.to_datetime("2018-04-03")
ndays = (end - start).days + 1
date_range = pd.to_timedelta(np.random.rand(n) * ndays, unit="D") + start
df = pd.DataFrame({"ind": date_range, 
                   "bill_amount": np.random.randint(10, 30, n), 
                   "cat": np.random.choice(["X", "Y", "Z"], n)})
df.set_index("ind", inplace=True)
#df.sort_index(inplace=True)
#this assumes that your dataframe has a datetime index

#here starts the actual calculation
total_sum = df.bill_amount.sum()
dataframe_slice = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).bill_amount.sum().div(total_sum)*100
dataframe_slice.plot()

#and we beautify the plot
plt.xlabel("Month of expenditure")
plt.ylabel("Percentage of expenditure")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time series kind stranger! I found out that I needed to do a groupby to the total sum too to get it right: `total_sum = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).bill_amount.sum()` to get what I need. However the .div really solved it for me, thanks!